# How to IP whitelist a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nat

So I have a kubernetes cluster running in Google Cloud. And from pods inside the cluster I need to access an external DB which has IP whitelisting configured. It seems that I need a static, shared IP for the cluster's outgoing traffic, what's the best approach?

Setting up a service IP seems irrelevant as that's for inbound traffic. I looked into [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview) and it seems promising, but I'm not exactly sure about how to set that up. Any docs/tutorial would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#google-compute-engine-gce) when traffic goes out of a kubernetes cluster in GKE it will get SNATed with the IP of the node. So you could whitelist the IPs of all GKE kubernetes cluster nodes.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services) is some best practices on connecting to external services from Kubernetes cluster. An [example](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=accessing%20external%20db%20in%20Google%20kubernetes&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) for connecting to Cloud SQL from Google Kubernetes Engine.

An [example](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example) setup of Cloud NAT on GKE.

Comment: Cloud NAT is likely the best option in this case. whitelisting the node IPs is not a good idea as the IPs might change.

Comment: Cloud NAT worked for me.  One followup issue is, I need to figure out how to expose services (or a proxy server) if I deploy to this cluster behind NAT.